# For If loops in batch files

Tags: batch-file

Can someone help me figure out why this doesnt work?  I mimic'd other for if loops, yet this isn't working.

```
echo Ping
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    @ping %%a 
    if "TTL=" > nul && (
        >> %log1% echo %%a
        echo Ping Successful to %%a
    ) else (
    >> %log2% echo %%a
    echo Ping failed to %%a
    )

)
```

Comment: Ahmm. You havent processed the result of ping command. You cant use `>` in batch files for comparisons - you need to use `GTR` . You can use conditional execution in if conditions like this.

Comment: @npocmaka I don't think, the `>` is meant for comparison, but for redirecting output to NUL (see my answer)

Comment: Consider reading the help for the commands you are trying to use before posting your question.  You can get the help for any Windows console command by typing a forward slash and question mark after the command name. `if /?`

Comment: @bill_steward delayedexpansion is not needed here and cmd is more than capable to perform this function.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  What exactly do you expect that code to do? What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem with mimicry. Lookalike doesn't mean Workalike.Your `if` syntax is complete nonsense and your `ping` does "only" ping but you have no way to process it's result. With a correct syntax, it would look something like:

```
echo Ping
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    ping %%a |find "TTL=" >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 (
        >> %log2% echo %%a
        echo Ping failed to %%a
    ) else (
        >> %log1% echo %%a
        echo Ping Successful to %%a
    )
)
```

or keeping your `&&` / `||` syntax:

```
echo Ping
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    ping %%a |find "TTL=" >nul && (
        >> %log1% echo %%a
        echo Ping Successful to %%a
    ) || (
        >> %log2% echo %%a
        echo Ping failed to %%a
    ) 
)
```